# Cannot connect postgres to pgadmin using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
services:
  pgdatabase:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - "./data_pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

I'm trying to connect to postgres using pgadmin but I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to connect to server: could not translate host name "pgdatabase" to address: Name does not resolve
```

Running `docker network ls` I get:

```
NAME                       DRIVER    SCOPE
bridge                     bridge    local
docker-sql-pg_default      bridge    local
host                       host      local
none                       null      local
```

Then running `docker network inspect docker-sql-pg_default` I get

```
[
    {
        "Name": "docker-sql-pg_default",
        "Id": "bfee2f08620b5ffc1f8e10d8bed65c4d03a98a470deb8b987c4e52a9de27c3db",
        "Created": "2023-01-24T17:57:27.831702189Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "8f53be84a95c9c0591df6cc6edb72d4ca070243c3c067ab2fb14c2094b23bcee": {
                "Name": "docker-sql-pg-pgdatabase-1",
                "EndpointID": "7f3ddb29b000bc4cfda9c54a4f13e0aa30f1e3f8e5cc1a8ba91cee840c16cd60",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bf2eb29b73fe9e49f4bef668a1f70ac2c7e9196b13350f42c28337a47fcd71f4": {
                "Name": "docker-sql-pg-pgadmin-1",
                "EndpointID": "b3a9504d75e11aa0f08f6a2b5c9c2f660438e23f0d1dd5d7cf4023a5316961d2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-sql-pg",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.13.0"
        }
    }
]
```

I tried to connect to the gateway IP 172.24.0.1 and the IP of postgres base 172.24.0.2 but I got timeout error. Why my network isn't running?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: if I copy and paste your `docker-compose.yaml` file locally, then `docker-compose up`, I can connect to `localhost:8080` to access pgadmin, and in pgadmin I can use hostname `pgdatabase` to connect to postgres.

Comment: What is your `docker-compose` version? 2.14.2 here

Comment: I see the same behavior both with `docker compose` using Docker client 20.10.23 and with `docker-compose` version 1.29.2.

Comment: @larsks I downgraded my docker compose to 1.29.2 and still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm also using WSL 2...

Comment: What are you using WSL 2 for?  Is that where docker is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I solved my problem using the following steps:

1. First I accessed the `pg-admin` container and I used `ping` to verify if the pgadmin could reach the postgres.
2. Since pgadmin was reaching postgres I used `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` to verify in my host machine the ports that are in use. surprisingly I have two instances of pgadmin running on 8080 (one bugged).
3. I used `docker-compose down` to stop the servers and used `docker system prune` to delete all images/containers...
4. I verified the used ports again and one pgadmin still running on 8080.
5. I used `pidof` to check the PID of running (bugged) pgadmin.
6. Then I used `kill -9` to kill the proccess.
7. Last, I used `docker-compose up -d` and I was able to communicate pgadmin with postgres via pgadmin interface.